# MonoTouch for iPad: how to remove Default splash image?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, splash-screen

I got an image called Default.png in my project folder and it shows up correctly as splash screen. It worked fine so far. However, for some reasons, the image suddenly shows upside down and I couldn't figure out how to fix it. At last, I thought, I can just remove the splash screen. Interestingly, I remove the reference to Default.png from my project, it still shows up. Then, I moved the Default.png to trash, but it still shows up. I guess MonoTouch cached it somehow? The same problem appears in both iPhoneSimulator and iPad device.

Only the splash image is upside down, everything else is okay. On simulator, one thing I notice is that the initial screen is shown in portrait mode, but all the icons are shown side ways (as if in landscape).

1. How can I turn around the upside down image?
2. if not possible to turn it around, how can I simply remove it?

Is this a bug in MonoTouch?

Comment: Okay, I kind of figured out how to turn the image upside down. I guess it was because I accidentally hit command arrow keys.